# Ajax wont execute a php code located in another file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to execute PHP code to update an entry in my database when the user clicks on a button with class `deleteitem`. Here's my AJAX/jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(".deleteitem").click(function() {
        var parent = $(this).closest('TR');
        var id = parent.attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "id=" + id,
            URL: "rejectRequest.php",
            success: function(msg) {
                $('#' + id).remove();
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

And here's my `rejectRequest.php` file

```
<?php
$DB_HOST     = 'localhost';
$DB_USER     = 'root';
$DB_PASSWORD = '';
$DB_DATABASE = 'recomdb';

//Connect to mysql server
$con = mysql_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD);
if (!$con) {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
}

//Select database
$db = mysql_select_db($DB_DATABASE);
if (!$db) {
    die("Unable to select database");
}

$id1 = intval($_POST['id']);

if (isset($id)) {

$query = "UPDATE  request SET  status =  'rejected' WHERE id = $id1";

mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
}
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

The JavaScript works fine: the  gets deleted. But the PHP won't execute.

When I captured what is being sent when I click the button, here's what it shows:

```
Request URL:http://localhost/recom/students_requests_copy(2).php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Header
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:ar,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:4
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host:localhost
Origin:http://localhost
Referer:http://localhost/recom/students_requests_copy(2).php
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.76 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
id:2
Response Headersview source
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Sun, 29 Sep 2013 12:40:27 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.19
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.19
```

**

### Why isn't it calling the rejectRequest.php file?

**

Comment: Your url in ajax method is good? your js and php are in the same folder?

Comment: @DonovanCharpin Everything works fine now, my problem was in parameter 'url', it should've been lowercase

Answer (score 2):

The parameter for the url is called `url` (lowercase), not `URL` (uppercase).

Answer (score 1):

In the ajax parameters, the `url` part should be in low case: the **url**, not **URL**:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(".deleteitem").click(function() {
        var parent = $(this).closest('TR');
        var id = parent.attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "id=" + id,
            url: "rejectRequest.php",
            success: function(msg) {
                $('#' + id).remove();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: One more think, dont use windows machine for work with code, that will broke your head, cause more of url and syntax most of time are no case sensitive and wne you go to a server on *nix probably work, not always, but when you do a change, it will broke, try with a linux machine

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
if (isset($id)) {
```

into this:

```
if (isset($id1)) {
```

On the side that you are using obsolete mysql, use mysqli or PDO. Also, you are prone to SQL Injection.

Comment: No he's not. `intval` is enough to prevent sql injection in that cas.

Comment: Right, overlooked intval.

Comment: thanks @sskoko, that was another error in my code, i've also read an article on why we shouldn't bother to convert from mysql to mysqli and that if we had the proper mechanisms of checking before any query, then we shouldn't be worried of sql injections